# Using try ...finally vs setImmediate nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I have an expressjs api route that triggers a function like this:

```
async function test() {
  try {
    //run some codes

    //hit another API endpoint with axios

    //return some response
  } catch (err) {
   //do some logging process
  }
}
```

I am trying to boost the performance a little by returning the response first then only hit the another API endpoint which is another webhook server. I am just unsure which one is a better way and if there is any implications to it.

try ...finally method

```
async function test() {
  try {
    //run some codes

    //return some response
  } catch (err) {
   //do some logging process
  } finally {
    //hit another API endpoint with axios
  }
}
```

using setImmediate. as I understand how nodejs works it will push it to the callstack and run in the background.

```
async function test() {
  try {
    //run some codes
    
    setImmediate(async () => {
     //hit another API endpoint with axios
    });

    //return some response
  } catch (err) {
   //do some logging process
  }
}
```

Comment: `setImmediate()` will postpone running it until your other code in this block finishes running and returns control back to the event loop.  It's essentially equivalent to `setTimeout(fn, 0)`.  If your other code has asynchronous operations itself, the `setImmediate()` only waits until control returns back to the event loop, not until all asynchronous operations are complete.  It's hard for us to see what you're really trying to accomplish here since you don't show the REAL issue here and instead just offer a theoretical question.  We could help better if we knew the real issue.

Comment: There is abit of delay for this specific API call as it needs to do:
1. Make some db related operations.
2. Make an API call to another server
3. Return a response.

Notes: The response does not rely on the api call at all

Comment: Well, these are all asynchronous so it doesn't cost you much to launch the operation and then go about whatever else you want to do.  It will immediately be running in the background anyway.  As I said above, if you show us your actual code, we can make a much more specific and educated recommendation that might even teach you some things you don't even know to ask.  That's why questions containing real code are usually more useful to the OP than theoretical questions.